# Заголовки на русском в графиках plotly в R при экспорте в файл

Tags: r, plotly

Пытаюсь рисовать графики в R c помощью plotly. Пока смотрю график в RStudio, всё прекрасно. После того, как экспортирую его в png с помощью orca, вместо русского текста получаю знаки вопроса.

Код для генерации графика

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
ir <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  layout(title = 'Ирисы',
         xaxis = list(title ='width', showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE), 
         yaxis = list(title = 'length', showgrid = FALSE),
         legend = list(font = list(size = 20)))
ir
orca(ir, "iris_orca.png", width = 5*250, height = 10*75)
```

Вот скрин из RStudio
[image: Скрин из RStudio]

А вот файл, полученный с помощью orca
[image: Файл, полученный с помощью orca]

```
> Sys.info()
          sysname           release           version          nodename           machine             login              user 
        "Windows"          "10 x64"     "build 19044" "LAPTOP-TSP7L2RG"          "x86-64"           "andre"           "andre" 
   effective_user 
          "andre"
```